# Automatically Adding 2 weeks to a Jquery UI date picker not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I have a jquery ui date picker on one of my projects, the requirement has me needing to select specific 2 week chunks at a time, I know I can make the date picker select 2 week chunks but I only need to allow the user to select specific 2 week chunks to select certain pay periods. What I'm trying to do is only allow the dates of the start of a payroll cycle to be selected and then select the date that follows 13 days after creating a 2 week range from start to finish. here is a JSFiddle link I have working with the start of payroll days as active and the rest disabled with a text box showing the date selected, The end date field is where i'm having trouble getting the date that follows 13 days after, Any help is greatly appreciated.

Link to JSFIDDLE-

http://jsfiddle.net/FuriousDuck/pxw3x8Lk/8/

HTML

```
<div id="date"></div>

Start Date  - <input type="text" id="start-date" value=""><br>
End Date   - <input type="text" id="end-date" value="13 Days Later Value"><br>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var availableDates = [
"2014-11-2",
"2014-11-16",
"2014-11-30"
];

function available(date) {
  ymd = date.getFullYear() + "-" + (date.getMonth()+1) + "-" + date.getDate();

  if ($.inArray(ymd, availableDates) != -1) {
    return [true, "","Available"];
  } else {
    return [false,"","unAvailable"];
  }





}

$('#date').datepicker(
  { 
    altField  : '#start-date',
    altFormat : 'yy-mm-dd',
    dateFormat: 'DD, d MM',
    beforeShowDay: available 
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `onSelect` listener to the datepicker to run a function whenever a different date is selected:

```
$('#date').datepicker(
{ 
    altField  : '#start-date',
    altFormat : 'yy-mm-dd',
    dateFormat: 'DD, d MM',
    beforeShowDay: available,
    onSelect: function() {
        var selectedDate = $('#date').datepicker('getDate');
        var endDate = new Date(selectedDate);
        endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate()+14);
        var endDateStr = (endDate.getYear()+1900)+'-'+(endDate.getMonth()+1)+'-'+endDate.getDate();
        $('#end-date').val(endDateStr);
    }
})
```

;